# Inserindo dados Condicionalmente no MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, if

Tenho uma tabela:
conluna1, coluna2, coluna3..As duas primeiras colunas tem dados inteiros, 0 e 1, já a terceira coluna está sem nem um registro. Gostaria de preencher esta coluna de acordo com uma condição, ou seja, se a coluna1 e a coluna2 estiverem preenchidas com o número 0, gostaria de preencher a coluna3 com o numero 0, senão, seria número 1.
Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize a cláusula `CASE` para realizar a decisão:

```
UPDATE tabela
   SET coluna3 = CASE
                   WHEN coluna1 = 0 AND coluna2 = 0 THEN 0
                   ELSE 1
                 END
```

> [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html)
>
> The CASE statement for stored programs implements a complex conditional construct.

Em tradução livre:

> A cláusula `CASE` para programas armazenados implementa uma estrutura condicional complexa.

Comment: Deu problema de buffer

Comment: Resolvi. Obrigado pelo código, ajudou bastaten.

Comment: Desculpe, não estou encontrando esse V, podes me dizer onde fica?

Comment: Ok, já vi e já cliquei.